# Top 5 count wrong for last week depending on week slicer

Tags: powerbi

I have two visuals showing the count of sales per client. I need to show the top 5 clients as per the profit. I have a bar chart showing the client and profit information.

Now, this week count of sales per client comes in the good order as the profit bar chart is also for this week.

But I need to show the count of sales per client last week as well and for this, I need to use the same customers for top 5 of the current week.

Here is my sample data:

[image]

The top 5 customers are different in week 25 and week 26.

**The counts are being filtered for last week itself, I need to show the counts last week for this week's top 5 customers.**

[image]

I have not used any Dax, just using columns sales count from the table.

Can anyone please let me know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Please show us your base data so we understand what we are looking at

Comment: Hey @Aldert Please check my updated question and let me know if I am still being unclear about my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all has to do with the interactions between your visuals. In your case, you do not want a cross interaction between the weeks:

Slicer1, should interact with Table1 only.
Slicer2, should interact with Table2 only.

To set this up, select Slicer1, you should see an extra tab in dutch (Indeling), see screenshot.
[image]

Select the "Edit interactions" (Interacties bewerken). You can now disable the interaction for Slicer2 and Table2.
So always select the visual (source) you want to control and disable the visuals which should not interact with it.

Comment: Please confirm if the answer helped you by setting answer to answered.

Comment: Hey @aldert, sorry I thought I checked your answer as the answer to my question. I have marked yours as the answer. Thanks for your help.